# Pyspark to load all files from list and print distinct value for each columns in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I would  like to run all these in parallel  1) Read files from the list  2)  print distinct value  from each  column of these tables, how can i replace the for loop below for parallel purpose ?

```
alist =['File_A','File_B']

mainfolder ='hdfs://1.2.3.4/home'

def loadfile(filename):
   file = spark.read_csv(mainfolder+str(filename))
   column  =  file.columns
   for i in column :
       printcol(i)

def printcol  (column) :
    print (s_df.toPandas()[column].unique())

for i in alist:
     loaddfile(i)
```

Comment: somehow i want to take advantage of spark with a cluster of workers

Comment: as it only apply to one function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get actually distinct values for all columns in one iteration and without using pandas:

```
import os    
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def load_file(filename: str):
    """
    Prints distinct values for all colmuns of the file `filename`
    Example output:
        Distinct values per column in file 'filename':
        +---+----------+------------+
        |c1 |c2        |c3          |
        +---+----------+------------+
        |a  |a,b,c,d,e |1,2,3,5,7,8 |
        +---+----------+------------+
    """

    df = spark.read.csv(os.path.join(mainfolder, filename), header=True)
    df = df.select(
        *[F.array_join(F.collect_set(c), ",").alias(c) for c in df.columns]
    )

    print(f"Distinct values per column in file '{filename}':\n", df._jdf.showString(1, 0, False))
```

To run this function in parallel for multiple files, you can use a `ThreadPool`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

alist =['File_A','File_B']

with ThreadPool(len(alist) or 1) as p:
    p.map(load_file, alist)
```